# JMS Message Listner is not consuming message for some time

Tags: jms

I have problemw with JMS Message listener, and its not consuming message from queue, once I restart server then its sending message form queue, no exception or error thrown.

onMessage() in message listener is not firing always..how to resolve the issue.

Even no Exception showed in the server logs.  I am using sun java server8.2

Then I tried to implement Exception listner on Connection but its throwing some other error

com.sun.messaging.jms.JMSException: MQRA:CA:Unsupported-setClientID() Exceptiion

here two problems 1 how to resolve Onmessage() issue to consume messages

second how to implement Exception listner.
here iam creating Queue connection and Session one time at GatewayServlet init() method

flow is GatewayServlet init()--> calls -->GatewayMessageReceiver init() method when GatewayServlet loads into sun java applicaiton server or deployed into sun java app server.

Then init() method in GatewayMessageReceiver class creates jms session and queue connection.

Here GatewayMessageReceiver implements Message listner class...

Here problem is onMessage() is not calling for some times, when I do restart server its calling  onMessage(). but it should call when ever message arrives in Queue, its not happning and no Error or Exception thrown.

I want to implement Exception listner but its thrwoing Errors

could you please help me in this case Ciaran McHale

please find below code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class GatewayServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private GatewayMessageReceiver receiver = null;


    /** Initializes the servlet.
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        receiver = new GatewayMessageReceiver();  //here iam calling my GatewayMessageReceiver for JMS connection creations
        info(""+receiver);
    }

    /** Destroys the servlet
     */
    public void destroy() {
        if (receiver != null) {
            receiver.destroy();
        }
    }


    protected void processGatewayRequest(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        //doing some business logic



    }

    protected void processRequest(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        CCMLogger.getGatewayLogger(GeneralConfigurator.getInstance().getUtility()).debug("Host sending request is:"+request.getRemoteHost());
        //check whether it's a push request
        processGatewayRequest(request, response);
    }
    /** Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    public void doGet(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        service(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        service(request, response);
    }


}
```

**and my JMS MESSAGE LISTNER IS**

```
import javax.jms.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import com.carrier.ccm.business.*;
import com.carrier.ccm.gateway.service.*;
import com.carrier.ccm.gateway.config.*;
import com.carrier.ccm.service.*;
import com.carrier.ccm.logging.*;
import com.carrier.ccm.util.*;
import com.carrier.ccm.exception.*;
/**
 *
 * @author  Administrator
 */
public class GatewayMessageReceiver implements MessageListener {

    private QueueConnection connection = null;

    /** Creates a new instance of GatewayMessageReceiver */
    public GatewayMessageReceiver() {
        super();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
      QueueSession  session     = null;
      QueueReceiver queueReceiver   = null;

      try{
        String queueName = "infoQueue";//its sun java app sever  queue name
        String qcfName = "infoQueueCF";//connectionfactory created in sun java app sever

        Logger.log.log(Level.INFO, "Queue name: "+queueName);            
        Logger.log.log(Level.INFO, "Queue CF name: "+qcfName);

        QueueConnectionFactory qcf = 
                (QueueConnectionFactory)JndiUtilities.get(qcfName);
        Logger.log.log(Level.INFO, "Queue CF: "+qcf);
        Queue queue = 
                (Queue)JndiUtilities.get(queueName);
        Logger.log.log(Level.INFO, "Queue: "+queue);
        // Creating a QueueConnection to the Message service");
        connection = qcf.createQueueConnection();
        // Creating a session within the connection
        session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        // Creating a QueueReceiver
        queueReceiver = session.createReceiver(queue);
        // setting up a message listener
        queueReceiver.setMessageListener(this);
        //Starting the Connection
        connection.start();
      } catch (Throwable t) {
           Logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to start queue listener for business messages", t);
      }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to close queue connection", t);
        }
    }

    public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message message) {
        String ut = null;
        try {
            String utm  = message.getStringProperty(IConstants.UTILITY_TAG);
            int bcDelay = message.getIntProperty(IConstants.BC_DELAY);

            //it must be an ObjectMessage!
            ObjectMessage omsg = (ObjectMessage)message;

           //Here iam doing business logic

        } catch (Throwable t) {            
          Logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to process business message", t);
        }
    }

}
```

THE JNDI UTILITIES CLASS

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author  Administrator
 */
public class JndiUtilities {
    private static Context context = null;

    static {
        setJndiContext();
    }

    /** Creates a new instance of JndiUtilities */
    private JndiUtilities() {
        super();
    }

    private static void setJndiContext() {
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR getting JNDI context: "+e);
        }    
    }

    public static Object get(String name) {
        if (context == null) {
            setJndiContext();
            if (context == null) return null;
        }

        Object obj;

        try {
            obj = context.lookup(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            obj = null;
            System.err.println("ERROR getting JNDI resource named \""+name+"\": "+e);
        }
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any code for people here to examine, so you are unlikely to get useful, detailed answers.

My guess is that your JMS client is failing somewhere in its initialisation, probably when calling `setClientID()`, but your code is (mis)using a `try-catch` clause to catch and *ignore* the exception. Without a proper connection to the JMS broker, your application will not receive any messages.

The JMS product you are using might have some demo applications. If so, then I suggest you examine them to see the coding steps that you could use to initialise your application and correctly deal with any exceptions that might be thrown. The demo applications might also show how to implement an `ExceptionListener`.

By the way, using an `ExceptionListener` does *not* mean that all exceptions will be reported to it. Your application code is still required to use `try-catch` clauses to determine when method invocations fail immediately/synchronously. The `ExceptionListener` function serves a different purpose, which is to notify your application when a problem occurs *asynchronously*.

Comment: hi any one could you answer this question

Comment: Even with an `ExceptionListener` (if your setup finished successfully and you are using a `MessageListener` always expecting messages pushed, never pulled) you can still see silent connection failures where the client still thinks it is connected but the server does not. I believe this is generally due to a poorly configured JMS system. You might want to look into configuring things like `keepalive` and `ping` timeouts to see if you can find the cause.